# Can "homo" be used as an impersonal pronoun?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary

In English, we can say "one must do this" or "one should do that", as a way of referring to any person, not just one person in specific. Can *homo* be used in a similar fashion in Latin (particularly in Classical Latin). Some example sentences:

> One should drink in moderation.

> One must not eat the yellow snow.

There was an answer to a translation question where the [lack of an impersonal pronoun](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/16222/5056) was mentioned, so I'm curious if this usage of *homo* would work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of *homo* as a genuine indefinite pronoun is definitely not good Classical Latin, but *homo* did have indefinite meaning from the very beginning, and by the Christian era Vulgar Latin was clearly well on its way to developing it into a true pronoun (cf. the Vulgate's *non in solo pane vivit homo*, often translated as "*one* does not live on bread alone"). Clear lines can be hard to draw, however; it's difficult to find a use of *homo* that can *only* be pronominal.

It's probably not the case that *homo* became a true pronoun before the separation of the Romance languages, but it was certainly close enough already that it only needed a gentle push to become one later on.
Probably the most famous surviving reflex is French *on* (from the nominative; compare that to the noun *homme*, from the accusative); for a while it was commonly believed to be the only one, but actually Catalan has *hom* (with or without the indefinite article *un*), and apparently a few Italian dialects still use *uomo*. The heyday of Italian pronominal *uomo* was the 13th century to the 15th, with only one attestation prior to that, in the 12th. Old Spanish also used *omne/hombre* (formally unambiguously from the accusative) as an indefinite pronoun, but stopped in the 16th century; it also doesn't seem to have done it before the 12th. The Eastern Romance does not preserve it, if it ever had it.

(Because of the prominence of French *on*, Germanic influence was often cited as the origin of the pronominal use of *homo* (cf. Dutch *men*, German *man*, Middle English *man/men*, all 3sg indefinite pronouns originating in the unstressed version of a word meaning 'man'), but given its original indefinite meaning, it's really not necessary.)

Classical Latin typically uses passive constructions (like the gerundives of the other answer) or 3rd person plurals without expressed pronouns (e.g. *dicent* often becomes "on dit" in French and "men zegt" in Dutch, though English does also render it as "they say") where other languages might use their impersonal or indefinite pronouns.

Comment: Great answer +1. My only comment is that I don't see anything particularly different about the usage of *homo* in the Vulgate. Isn't this just a so-called "gnomic present" about humans as a kind? It's not clear to me what the boundary between that and a quasi-pronoun is. See, for instance, Seneca: "Magna scilicet laus est si homo mansuetus homini est." (Many of the results for "homo" in Seneca--with his tendency for aphorisms--are similar.)

Comment: The Vulgate of Matt. 4,4 is a literal translation of Οὐκ ἐπ’ ἄρτῳ μόνῳ ζήσεται ὁ ἄνθρωπος. Hence, I do not think it is a very good example for impersonal homo.

Answer (score 4):

I'd express this as **bibendum est cum temperantia** and **nives albicerae edendae non sunt** without any need for an impersonal pronoun.

Comment: Ahh! Thanks. I always forget that you can have subjectless sentences in Latin.

Comment: @Adam You could consider the gerund(ive) the subject of the first sentence, and *nives* of the second. In constructions like these the grammatical subject might have nothing to do with the "semantic subject".

Answer (score 3):

I can't find any evidence of Latin using *homo* as an impersonal pronoun. It might be interesting to note that the nominative case of Old French *hom* becomes *on*, which is used as an impersonal pronoun in French, while the oblique *home* became *homme*, meaning man.

As for Latin, the passive voice was used instead of any impersonal pronoun. This meant that for intransitive verbs, they really did become impersonal. The verb *ire* was used in the third person passively, *itur*, to basically mean "one goes".

Allen and Greenough's Latin Grammar states in a footnote:

> With impersonal verbs the word it is used in English, having usually no representative in Latin, though id, hōc, and illud are often used nearly in the same way.

Overall, a solid translation of "One must not eat yellow snow" is "Nix flava edenda non est", using the future passive participle (gerund) to show necessity.